# OLS vs Random Effect

Tags: least-squares, panel-data, random-effects-model, categorical-encoding

I am running my regression on Stata. Because I am observing 9 countries over 4 years, I am using panel data. Following the suggested steps from the literature, I have first run an OLS model with countries and year dummies and got an R-squared of 0.8149. Subsequently, I run GLS Random-effect (RE) with month dummies and i(country), overall R-squared  0.7409. If I include country variables in the latter my r-squared becomes 0.8355. After performing the Breusch-Pagan test (xttest0), the results confirm in both cases to pursue RE.

My questions are:

1. Do I need to include month and country variables in RE?
2. If the R-squared for OLS is > than the RE one but xttest0 still support the RE, which one should I pursue?

Thank you.

Comment: ols will always have bigger R2 *within sample* than RE, because OLS is directly minimizing R2. That does not mean the model is better or that it would perform better in the test set.